What strategy would you recommend for a web page with 300+ reviews?
I have a site where some of our products have 300+ reviews on the product page. It's a WordPress / WooCommerce site with Yoast SEO installed. For a positive user experience, I've broken up the comments into multiple pages so the page doesn't look incredibly long. The Yoast SEO plugin alerts me that breaking comments into multiple pages is a bad practice.
I'm a bit lost on what to do. I don't want to sacrifice user experience and having them scroll forever (the majority of the page is reviews).
Would you:

Break comments into pages
Contain the reviews in a container that has an overflow: scroll and a max-heightso the container doesn't take up as much space (I'm not sure on the UX of this)
Something else?

Thanks for any advice.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51801/latest-ui-research-for-comments-sections[https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51801/latest-ui-research-for-comments-sections]

https://app.uxcel.com/courses/common-patterns/comments-best-practices-499[https://app.uxcel.com/courses/common-patterns/comments-best-practices-499]

It seems like a delicate balance you want to achieve. I don't know how the review work on those platforms. Maybe, if you are able to, you could have a button on your page that would load the comments. This would:

Probably make the page load faster
Make it so Google's crawl would include the main page content mostly
While still allowing those who want to, access to the entire repo of reviews for your product.

I have seen this a lot on blogging / new sites with their comment sections. I would think you could do the same for reviews.
